# Delay appears when I am trying to register double click event on NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, double-click

I have NSTableView and NSView inside of this table using as cell. This NSView has 3 NSTextFields.

When I'm trying to select one of this NSTextFields they respond really quickly. But if I add some code to register double click event on NSTableView, delay appears. So when I click on textfield it thinks half a second and then activates it. But there is no such delay without double click event registered.

My code:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [tasksList setDoubleAction:@selector(doubleClickInTable:)];
    [tasksList setTarget:self];

}

-(void)doubleClickInTable:(id)sender
{
    //Don't matter, it can be empty.

}
```

Comment: Isn't that what you'd expect?  My guess is that the delay is the configured time between the two clicks and after half a second it times-out and allows the text field to gain focus.  I'm just guessing though...

Comment: After NSTextField activation my CPU activity is about 50 %. I checked this on empty project and it repeated. Just create NSTableView with NSTableCellView and NSTextField inside, launch your app and activate textfield. And you will see. What's wrong?

Comment: I just added [myTable setSelectionHighlightStyle:NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone] and delay disappeared. But CPU overload is still here.